# Div with a text and button to be blue background

Tags: html, css

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0gfnr3/) code

```
<div id="maincontainer">
            <img id="image" src="http://i.share.pho.to/b75f672b_o.jpeg" title=""> 
             <div id="container">
                    <h1 class='jtextfill' id="h1">
                    This is a sample text
                    </h1>
             <button class="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button> 
            </div>
</div>
```

I have a maincontainer which has a background image and a div. The inner div has a text and image. This is what I have done.

I want my final html to look like this. Sorry I am using paint to make my final output and the button is changed from oval to square. Just skip that point. My idea is to have button just below the text and maincontainer div background should be blue.

[image]

I want like this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muxw7hx1/1/) but the button positioning should be at the bottom. I used top to change it but it is fixed

Comment: What CSS Have you tried??

Comment: @Jhecht i tried top:150px in .btn to move the button but the position is not changing. Also used txt in place of h2 in the css because text and button is in container so it should be blu but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'd place both the `h1` title and the button in the `bluebg` div container which is inside the :

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="bluebg">
    <h1>
    This is a sample text
    </h1>

    <button class="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button> 
</div>
</div>
```

Add the image as the background to your `#container` id:

```
#container {
    background-image: url(http://i.share.pho.to/b75f672b_o.jpeg);
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Set the bluebg container's background color:

```
.bluebg {
    background-color:#0000FF;
}
```

And remove the absolute positioning of `h1`:

```
h1 {
    background-color:#0000FF;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aLuctvm6/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/muxw7hx1/1/ i want like this but button position is not changing

Comment: Use mine http://jsfiddle.net/aLuctvm6/3/ and add a margin to the `.btn` class to move it around. For example: `.btn {margin-top: 20px;}`.

Comment: nop the position should be fixed if i change the text or if the text is null then the position changes

Comment: Okay, then just use `position: fixed;` to position the button: http://jsfiddle.net/muxw7hx1/3/ Add the top/left/right/bottom positions in pixels to the `.btn` class.

Answer (score 0):

latest update:

In response to comment-
I guess you just need to add style="background:blue;" then.

```
<div id="maincontainer" style="background-image:url(http://i.share.pho.to/b75f672b_o.jpeg); width:350px; height:300px; position:relative;">
             <div id="container" style="background:blue; position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px; padding:15px; margin:15px;">
                    <h1 class='jtextfill' id="h1">This is a sample text</h1>
             <button class="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button> 
            </div>
</div>
```

I think this is what you're looking for. If you know what you're doing with CSS then you obviously want to take it out of the line and into your stylesheet. If you don't know what you're doing with CSS then just leave it there, it'll be fine.

```
<div id="maincontainer" style="background-image:url(http://i.share.pho.to/b75f672b_o.jpeg); width:200px; height:200px;">
             <div id="container">
                    <h1 class='jtextfill' id="h1">This is a sample text</h1>
             <button class="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button> 
            </div>
</div>
```

If you want the text and button to be at the bottom of your container DIV, then you need to add a little more inline CSS, the whole HTML code will look like this

```
<div id="maincontainer" style="background-image:url(http://i.share.pho.to/b75f672b_o.jpeg); width:200px; height:200px; position:relative;">
             <div id="container" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px;">
                    <h1 class='jtextfill' id="h1">This is a sample text</h1>
             <button class="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button> 
            </div>
</div>
```

to get your positioning just right, you will need to increase the :0px; to perhaps :5px; or :10px; for example.

Comment: nop i am not doing this i have a container which has a text and button and that backgound should be blue

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this - but quick and dirty approximation of your image above:

```
#maincontainer {
    background:url('http://i.share.pho.to/b75f672b_o.jpeg');
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
}
#container {
    width:90%;
    height:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:4%;
    padding:1%;
    background:blue;
    color:#ffffff
}
.btn {
    width:40%;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:5px 2px;
    background:lightblue;
    border:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    bottom:20px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/56gb3gvq/2/)

Comment: thanks but how can i move the button positioning? i want to move it bit up

Comment: sorry still cant move my button positioning

Comment: See the revised fiddle (link above) - and just change the numbers for left and bottom in the CSS for `.btn`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that I think is what you are describing
http://jsfiddle.net/ps0gfnr3/1/

The big changes are

- making the image a `background-image` of the outer div, that way putting additional elements on top makes more sense and are easier to position
- using the container for the blue box, elements like span or h1 shouldn't be given css properties like `width` and `height`.

Comment: in that way i can not move the button position if you see my image then button is at te bottom of the div

Answer (score 0):

I use the div container the `position:absolute`, but the main container `position:realite` for do the effect.

```
#maincontainer{
    position:relative;
}

#container{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:10px;
        background-color:#0000FF;
}
h1 {

color:#FFFFFF;

}
.btn {
  display:block;
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;top:590px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

The example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muxw7hx1/)

Comment: want like this http://jsfiddle.net/muxw7hx1/1/ but the button position should be at the bottom, i tried using top but it is not changing

Comment: Try using: margin-top: 20 px for example.

Comment: tried that and top as well but not the position is fixed